# What is the grammatical error in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Knowing that they will have to deal with the consequences of eliciting
>   another's enmity makes islanders more cautious about what they say or
>   do.

I know it doesn't have very good flow, but is it grammatically correct? My English tutor says no, but I don't know what differentiates that sentence from, say, a phrase like *"baking makes me happy"* or *"realizing I had homework to do made me eager to get home."*

Comment: Did you ask your tutor what the exact issue was?

Comment: She said something about a reduced clause, and that "baking" is a simple action while "knowing" implies something... more, and that's why they can't be used the same way. I was feeling pretty confused so I didn't really catch everything she said lol. She also said I should phrase it like this instead: _"Knowing that they will have to deal with the consequences of eliciting another's enmity, islanders are more cautious about what they say or do."_ I agree that sounds less awkward, but I'm not sure why my version is considered **wrong**.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the sentence, and your tutor's emendation turns it from a simple SVO sentence (albeit wih complex S and O) to a more complex sentence with a small clause modifying the S.

Comment: I agree with Collin: this construction is OK. Her suggestion just turns into a different, equally fine construction. Perhaps she meant that it is a bit hard to parse this way? Because I do think the gerund construction is a tad long and complicated. P.S. I'd say "*one/each* another's enmity". Unless that's not what you mean.

Comment: I can't see anything wring with it either.  It's long winded and wordy, and could be re-written differently.  But that doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, thanks all. I'll try asking more specifically what she finds to be the issue to be next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I see no grammatical error with this sentence. Yes, it's a mouthful, but it is grammatically correct. Your tutor's suggested sentence is also correct, and may be more common than your sentence, but they both express the same idea.

Comment: Is this a personal feeling, or do you have a reason to conclude that the sentence (and the tutor's) is correct?